# I cannot use pipe's write and read function after read and write once in loop

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork

I am learning pipes and I'm triying to process comunication with ordinary pipe. Following code writes once but it doesn't write or read again. What is the problem of that?

Edit:Yes, I removed close() parts but, it cannot completely read because write doesn't finish yet.

Ex:
Write: Hello

Read: He

Read: llo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 25
#define READ_END    0
#define WRITE_END   1

int main(void)
{
char write_msg[BUFFER_SIZE] = "Game Started";
char read_msg[BUFFER_SIZE];

pid_t pid; 
int fd[2];    // an array of 2 integers fd[0] and fd[1]

if (pipe(fd) == -1) { fprintf(stderr,"Pipe failed"); return 1;}

pid = fork();

if (pid < 0) { fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed"); return 1; }
while(1){
    if (pid > 0) { 
        sprintf(write_msg,"Hello %d",rand());
        write(fd[WRITE_END], write_msg, strlen(write_msg)+1); 

    }
    else { /* child process */
        int status = read(fd[READ_END], read_msg, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if(status != -1)
        printf("child read1: %s\n                     *********************************\n",read_msg);
    }

}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: How do you expect to write more after you do `close(fd[WRITE_END]);`? Same with the reading and the closing of the pipe there.

Comment: Also, always do error checking for `write` as well.

Comment: So, how can I block write while reading? any comments?

Comment: You really don't have to. If the pipe fills up, then `write` will block until it can send the data through the pipe. Same with `read`, if there's nothing to read it will block until there is.

Comment: But, pipe doesn't fill. Child always reads while parent writes. So parent can write some of characters until child reads

Comment: I don't really see what problem you have, once you remove those `close` calls (which is the current problem you ask about) Why do you think you need those `close` calls? What do you want to happen in each process? Please try to give us more details.

Comment: It happens, I am trying to sent 6-7 character but it reads partial.

Ex: Message : "Hello World"

read1:"Hell"

read2:"o Wold"

Comment: Okay, my memory was wrong, the *writes* will be atomic, but the reads doesn't have to be.

Comment: yes maybe it writes atomic and read cannot, so ı see partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to think about pipes is to think of *actual* pipes that you have in your home. Water (or other fluids) flow from one end to the other. If you continuously fill the pipe at one end using buckets of water, at the other end there's no way to distinguish which bucket delivered the water currently flowing out.

It's basically the same with computer pipes: Bytes flow from one end to the other, without any specific kind of message boundaries. If you need a boundary, you need to add it yourself. And in a way you already *do* that, as you include the string null-terminator in the data you send.

Since you have a "message end byte" (the string null-terminator), a simple way to make sure you receive a full message is to read byte by byte in a loop, until you get to the null-terminator. Once you have the terminator you can then display the message, and go back to read the next message.

In *pseudo-ish* code it might look something like this:

```
char ch;
while (read(pipe_read_fd, &ch, 1) == 1)
{
    if (ch == '\0')
    {
        // End of message, print the buffer
    }
    else
    {
        // Append character to buffer
    }
}
```